# Writing a table in a text file

Tags: python, formatting

I am trying to write a condensed list of music tracks,times that they have been played and the artist to a text file in tabular form.

However currently the tracks are in list form, i.e.

```
08:04:10 Current Track Playing = Skinny Genes - Eliza Doolittle 

08:07:09 Current Track Playing = Keep On Walking - Scouting For Girls 

08:10:45 Current Track Playing = Thinking of Me - Olly Murs 

08:14:01 Current Track Playing = Hangin' On A String - Loose Ends 

08:17:34 Current Track Playing = Together Again - Janet Jackson
```

Throughout the text file.

My code looks like this

```
open('log','w').writelines([(line[:33]+line[42:])
    for line in open(fl) if "Current Track Playing" in line])
```

Any ideas on how to put the data into a table rather than just a list?

Comment: By "table" do you mean an ASCII art style table with justified column lengths, or *data* representing a table, like CSV?

Comment: Why is this marked `tkinter`?

Comment: @LukasGraf a data representing table, sorry for confusion

Comment: @iCodez this is marked tkinter as I am writing the program within tkinter

Comment: "a data representing table" in what format? Be exact.

Comment: To be more exact I would like to write the file 'log' in HTML and have the content to be in a table with Time, Track Name and Artist as separate columns

Answer (score 1):

Use [`csv.writer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) to write CSV-style data to files.

Example:

```
import csv
import re

pattern = re.compile('([0-9]*:[0-9]*:[0-9]*) Current Track Playing = ([^-]*?) - ([^-]*)$')

csv_file = open('music.csv', 'wb')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file,
                        delimiter=';',
                        quotechar='"',
                        quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

with open('music.log', 'r') as music_log:
    for line in music_log:
        timestamp, song, artist = pattern.match(line.strip()).groups()
        csv_writer.writerow([timestamp, song, artist])

csv_file.close()
```

(This assumes you've already done the stripping of the numerical IDs from the log you asked about in another question).

Output:

```
08:04:10;Skinny Genes;Eliza Doolittle
08:07:09;Keep On Walking;Scouting For Girls
08:10:45;Thinking of Me;Olly Murs
08:14:01;Hangin' On A String;Loose Ends
08:17:34;Together Again;Janet Jackson
```